# Android billing v3 - no signature

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

What I want?
After retrieving all purchased items I need to verify the purchase on my server, this I want to do with the signature and signed data received from the in-app payment.

First I used the in-app billing v2 there I got every time with my developer account a correct signature and signdata for the static test sku `android.test.purchased`.

I switched to the new billing v3 because it seems very nice to implement, however I get no signature any more.

I have uploaded a previous version of my APK to Google (don't published ever because it is not finished yet), also I added a active in-app product for further testings.

The upload of the APK was yesterday 10:00 pm so I think also I have waited enough.

What I tried?
I have installed my application in different version:

- unsigned apk with my self added "active" in-app product => no signature
- unsigned apk with the sku `android.test.purchased` => no signature
- signed apk with my self added "active" in-app product => no signature
- signed apk with the sku `android.test.purchased` => no signature

Those 4 "app states" I tried both my developer phone (where my primary Google account is the same user as the developer console account) and with a test account on setup another phone, the test account is also placed in my account settings under "test accounts".

Hmm and now I have no more ideas how I get my signature.
I think I will get the signature with an active app + active in-app product because the payment process works (The adb logcat displays that I purchased the "Android.test.purchased")
My self created in-app product I could also not test because if I use my developer account, the play store tells me "can not buy, already owned" and with my test account I got an error "This product is not available for your account".

Do you have a solution for my problem?

Comment: @lunarnet76, what the data is, is really simple. the signdata is the data which google send back to your account, the data tells you about the purchase state, and the signature can be used with your public app key to verify the signdata was not manipulated and that google has send it

Comment: prdarur. I am having the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: Not for now, but by reading other posts which says "google's depricated says only that you should not use it but it will not get removed" i decided to stay on V2, because there my implementation worked as expected. But i do not stop searching for a solution with V3. Because i verify the payment through my server V2 let me do this without providing the public key within the app which is very nice, i only have the public key on my server which verifies. With V3 i think this is also not possible.

Comment: @prdatur Any solutions yet? Having the same problem.

Comment: Not for now, Still using V2 because of the problem.

Comment: Nope, still no solution.

Answer (score 2):

I found with V3 that the test products do not return any signed data, but if you sign your app with your release key and complete the purchase flow of your actual products that you do get signed data.

Comment: See my "testings" -> signed apk with my self added "active" in-app product => no signature

Answer (score 1):

You no longer get signatures for test purchases (android.test.*). I took the dive and uploaded my app to the market place (just didn't publish it) using my real products.

Low and behold signatures started to be returned! I recommend amending any server side validation you are using to skip the signature check when the data contains an android.test.* item id.

Note: The important bit about the above is: "using my real products".

Comment: Hello, but see my testing for "signed apk with my self added "active" in-app product => no signature" i also had added an "real" product and it doesn't gave me a signature ether.

Comment: Hi, all I can say is that it is working for me. Obviously I am using an account that is registered as one of the developers of the app. Only difference I can think of is that the app is a published one, just the apk in question is in an unpublished state (next release).

Comment: And i think this is the problem. an unpublished app (never published) will get no signature, it had been published for a while. the in app feature does not need to be currently published, but the app itself. But that behaviour is for me a no go, it must be possible to get signatures with a never published app.